# Variance Calculation for Var(a + (b^2)Y)

Tags: variance

What is $\mathsf{Var}(a + (b^2)Y)$ equal to?

I understand that $\mathsf{Var}(aX + bY) = a^2\cdot \mathsf{Var}(X) + b^2\cdot \mathsf{Var}(Y) + 2(a\cdot b)\cdot\mathsf{Cov}(X, Y)$, but not sure how to calculate what $\mathsf{Var}(a + (b^2)Y)$ is equal to.

Answer (score 2):

$Var(a + b^2Y)=Var(b^2Y)=b^4 Var(Y)$

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathsf{Var}(\alpha X + \beta Y+\gamma) = \alpha^2\cdot \mathsf{Var}(X) + \beta^2\cdot \mathsf{Var}(Y) + 2(\alpha\cdot \beta)\cdot\mathsf{Cov}(X, Y)$

Substitute $\alpha\gets 0,\\ \beta\gets b^2,\\ \gamma\gets 0$